# If I want to exclude some properties from Codable, why those properties must be Optional?

Tags: swift, codable

I have the following `struct`

```
struct Checklist : Codable {
    let id: Int64
    var text: String?
    var checked: Bool
    var visible: Bool
    var version: Int64

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case text
        case checked
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting compiler error

> Type 'Checklist' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

The only way I can solve, is by changing the excluded properties, into Optional.

```
struct Checklist : Codable {
    let id: Int64
    var text: String?
    var checked: Bool
    var visible: Bool?
    var version: Int64?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case text
        case checked
    }
}
```

May I know why this is so? Is this the only right way to resolve such compiler error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They need not be optionals, but they must have some initial value, e.g.

```
struct Checklist : Codable {
    let id: Int64
    var text: String?
    var checked: Bool
    var visible: Bool = false
    var version: Int64 = 0

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case text
        case checked
    }
}
```

Otherwise those properties would be undefined when an instance is created from an external representation, via the synthesized

```
init(from decoder: Decoder)
```

method. Alternatively you can implement that method yourself, ensuring that all properties are initialized.

Optionals have an implicit initial value of `nil`, that's why your solution works as well.

Comment: @cheok-yan-cheng, little explanation of why it happens: Basically, when you declare type `Decodable`(`Codable` is `Decodable` and `Encodable` at the same time) implicit `constructor` gets created that will init fields using decoder.  And if you have `CodingKey` enum it will use only specified field, and rest of the fields would be ignored in that implicit constructor, so they would have no value set.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.